# Fibonacci implementation in assembly giving unexpected results

Tags: assembly, x86, fibonacci

I'm trying to write an assembly code version of Fibonacci which gives the nth Fibonacci number and returns it.

For some reason it is having trouble storing the return value of the Fibonacci numbers and adding them.

I want it to print the nth Fibonacci number.

I have made some modifications to my code, now it is still incorrect, but it's closer. Now it tells me that the 11th fibonacci number is 48. Still incorrect, but we're getting somewhere right?

```
.text

    .globl _fibonacci
_fibonacci:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    push %esi
    movl 8(%ebp),%esi

    cmp $1,%esi
    jle BASE
    sub $1,%esi
    push %esi
    call _fibonacci
    add $4,%esp
    movl %eax,%edx
    sub $1,%esi
    push %esi
    call _fibonacci
    add $4,%esp
    add %eax,%edx
    movl %edx,%eax

DONE:
    pop %esi
    pop %ebp
    ret

BASE:
    mov $1,%eax
    jmp DONE
```

I'm calling this assembly code using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n);

int main(void){
  int n=111;
  int x=fibonacci(n);
  printf("The %d fibonaacci number is %d\n",n,x);
}
```

Comment: this code has exponential asymptotic growth.. don't do that.

Comment: running time is not a big concern for me, I just want something that gives the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to be more careful with register usage across the recursive calls.

Your code assumes that `%edx` retains its value across the second call.

However, this is not the case, because `_fibonacci` changes it.

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive calls are clobbering `%edx`. You need to `pushl %edx` in your prologue and `popl %edx` in your postlogue, like so:

```
.text

    .globl _fibonacci
/* fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) */
_fibonacci:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edx  /* <-- PUSH TO SAVE BEFORE CLOBBERING */
    movl 8(%ebp),%esi

    /* 0th and 1st numbers are defined to be 1. */
    cmpl $1,%esi
    jle BASE

    /* find fib(n-1) */
    subl $1,%esi
    pushl %esi
    call _fibonacci

    addl $4,%esp
    movl %eax,%edx  /* <-- %edx CLOBBERED! */

    /* find fib(n-2) */
    subl $1,%esi
    pushl %esi
    call _fibonacci

    addl $4,%esp
    addl %edx,%eax

DONE:
    popl %edx  /* <-- POP TO RESTORE AFTER CLOBBERING */
    popl %esi
    popl %ebp
    ret

BASE:
    movl $1,%eax
    jmp DONE
```

Using this driver:

```
// BUILD -arch i386 ONLY
// clang -arch i386 fib.s fibo.c -o fibo
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n);

void Test(int i) {
  int r = fibonacci(i);
  printf("fib(%d) -> %d\n", i, r);
}

int main(void){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Test(i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Test run looks like:

```
$ ./fibo 
fib(0) -> 1
fib(1) -> 1
fib(2) -> 2
fib(3) -> 3
fib(4) -> 5
fib(5) -> 8
fib(6) -> 13
fib(7) -> 21
fib(8) -> 34
fib(9) -> 55
```

Comment: Im a newbie in assembly but if I would change popl %esi and %epb in DONE to leave. And then subl $2, esi to find n-2, would that work or not?

Comment: @fangio Why don't you try it and see?